# Vaadin Label not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, label, vaadin, vaadin7

In Vaadin Label , I set a html content as  String . That html  is consisted of a html form and  javascript+jquery related stuff for form submission and other processing.

Even though the form is  correctly loaded to the UI , the javascript stuff is not working .

So what can be the reason ? . Is there any otherway to do this ?

Comment: `the javascript stuff is not working` what happens? Are some errors shown in the browser console?

Comment: No . even the simple alerts are not working , couldn't figure-out the reason

Comment: Have you looked at the generated source sent to the browser? I might think that the vaadin framework prevents such JS injections for security reasons...

Comment: once my colleague done this , may be helpful to you <div/> <a href ="" onclick="<script>......</script>" > placed a div inside a custom layout, you can try with some variations

Answer (score 0):

To execute JavaScript from your server-side Vaadin code you should API provided by the JavaScript class, e.g.:

```
com.vaadin.ui.JavaScript.execute("alert('Hello World');");
```

But you must be very careful when you using this API, so I recommend this only for very simple JavaScript. For more complex cases you must create your own widget or extension by using GWT or Javascript on the client side.